# How to programmatically access views?

Tags: basic4android

I have a lot of views. And I like to have them placed in the program, taking the size of the screen in account. But I have a problem accessing the views in a loop.

Now, I have to take one view at the time:

```
view1.top = xdip
view2.top = xdip
```

What I really want to do is:

```
for c = 1 to 40
    view(c).top = ...
next
```

But I can't get it to work. 
Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=47508).

Here is an example:

```
For i = 0 To Activity.NumberOfViews - 1
    Dim v As View
    v = Activity.GetView(i)
    v.Top = 30dip
Next
```

Comment: I have seen this, but how do I know what view is what view? 
Do the view's number get in the order I create them?

Comment: You can add your views to a List or array. It will be easier to handle specific views this way.

Comment: Thanx for the tip! I may not go insane this week :)